# Are there different ways to pronounce お column (or related sounds) like こ, そ, の, etc?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

I have noticed two different pronunciations for お column and related sounds (お, の, を）.

For the first one, お is pronounced like `aw` as in `al`ways, の is like `no` as in British  pronunciation of `not` (nawt).

For the second one, お is like `oh`, and よ is like `yo` as in `Yo, what's up?`

Are both of them corrent pronunciations?

Comment: Since we are talking about phonetics, it should be noted there is no singular "British pronunciation of not". In RP (Received Pronunciation) that vowel is actuated as an [open-mid back rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_rounded_vowel) or [open back rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_back_rounded_vowel), but I am pretty sure in some parts of England, you'll hear the [open back unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_back_unrounded_vowel) in that word, which sounds closer to /a/. Also I am not sure what phone it is in your "yo" example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two sounds are not distinguished in Japanese. They are free allophones of the same phoneme /o/.

Comment: I am not very clear on the "two different pronunciations" that OP differentiates. That's why I wonder if your answer implies confirmation that OP's differentiation is valid and exists in other languages, though it may not exist in Japanese. (since phonemes and allophones are language-specific)

Comment: @EddieKal - I understood the first as referring to the [open-mid back rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_rounded_vowel) [ɔ] and the second as the [close-mid back rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_back_rounded_vowel) [o]. If the OP heard the first in Japanese, it must sometimes occur (for a speaker of Burmese, at least).

Comment: I ruled out the [open back rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_back_rounded_vowel) [ɒ] because Japanese /o/ rarely gets so open.

Comment: Yes, the first is  [ɔ] and the second one is [o].
[Here](https://ja.forvo.com/word/%E9%A3%B2%E3%82%80/) I can only hear native japanese speakers saying `not mu` instead of `no mu`. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @HanMoeHtet - Openness is not the only difference between the vowels of the English words "not" and "no," though. The latter is a diphthong [ou]. In what Japanese words do you hear /o/ pronounced like that?

Comment: Sorry it's not really `no mu`, it's [o].

Comment: Many beginner lessons introduce お as [o]. But I find [ɔ] more common when I listen to Japanese. I'd like to know if I'm mishearing it or people hear [ɔ] as well. Just curious.

Comment: @HanMoeHtet I don't hear [ɔ]. To me the open-mid back rounded vowel [ɔ] sounds clearly distinct from and too open to be the Japanese vowel in コ or オ. The close-mid back rounded vowel [o] sounds pretty close and could actually be the vowel I use when I speak Japanese. For reference, Wikipedia suggests the most common phone (sound) for that vowel is the [mid back rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_back_rounded_vowel) [o̞].